# Search common characters in strings and return pointer to the common character (without using strpbrk)

Tags: c, string, bash, pointers

Following code finds the common character in two strings and returns a pointer to the common string if any. I'm trying to emulate the function strpbrk without using any builtin functions or subscripts.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



char *find_char( char const *source, char const *chars ){

    char* str1;
    char* str2;

    if (source == NULL || chars == NULL)
        return NULL;

     else {

        for( *str1=&source != '\0'; ++str1;){
            for( *str2=&chars != '\0'; ++str2;){

                if (*str1 == *str2)

                    return str1;

                else return NULL;}

    }

}
}

char* main(){  
    char const *source = "ab";
    char const *chars = "bc";
    find_char(source, chars);
}
```

But I'm getting the following error

> Running "/home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-c-world.c"
>   bash: line 12: 29755 Segmentation fault      "$file.o" $args
>   Process exited with code: 139

I am a beginner at C and learning how to manipulate pointers, please let me know what am I doing wrong and how I can strengthen my C programming skills, right now I'm mostly using Kenneth Reek's book "Pointers on C"

Thanks

Comment: I cant assign a const char* to a char *

Answer (score 0):

Various `ìf` logic and runaway pointer problems. Fixed code below:

```
char *find_char( char const *source, char const *chars ){

    char* str1;
    char* str2;

    if (source != NULL && chars != NULL) {
       for( str1=source; *str1; str1++){
           for( str2=chars; *str2; str2++){
               if (*str1 == *str2) return str1;
           }
       }
    }
    return NULL;
}

char* main(){  
    char const *source = "ab";
    char const *chars = "bc";
    char *x;
    x = find_char(source, chars);
    if (x != NULL) printf("%c", *x);
}
```

Comment: can you explain the runaway pointer problems? or suggest where I can get my pointer orientation right. Thanks

Comment: @SundasWaheed The main problem is in the `for` statements. The loop will not terminate as intended because `*str2=&chars != '\0';` not only overwrites `*str2` (= "the memory position at address`str2`") with `&chars` (= the address of `chars`), but in addition this assignment will never return 0 (because `&chars` is a non-zero address), and the loop will thus continue forever (leading to a segmentation fault). What you actually need to do is to initialize the pointer `str2` with the address of `chars`, as I did in the code in my answer. Same applies to the other `for` loop with `str1`.

Comment: @SundasWaheed It's all about the difference between `str2` and `*str2`, `chars` and `&chars`, and what the code refers to. The address, or the memory content pointed to by that address.